# How to start JBoss AS 7.1.1 on Windows?

Tags: java, jboss, java-ee-7

I am new to `JBOSS`.I downloaded `jboss-as-7.1.1.Final.zip`and unzip this zip file.
Then I go to bin folder and double click on standalone.bat but new cmd window open and close within 2 -3 sec.

I tried to start server throught cmd.I open cmd in 2 ways

1.normally mode

1. Run as Admin (Admin Mode).

In 2 ways I get:

`Calling "P:\Software\JBOSS\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin\standalone.conf.bat"
'findstr' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

then it stops.

So the JBoss server does not start.

I added Environment Variables like.

`JBOSS_HOME : P:\Software\JBOSS\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final`

`JAVA_HOME : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21`

How can I run JBoss server and deploy projects in it on Window 7?

Comment: Have you tried standalone.bat ??

Comment: Could you try with [JBoss EAP 6.1](http://www.jboss.org/products/eap)? If it still appears, feel free to [file a bug](http://issues.jboss.org).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the following value to Right Click My Compuer -> Advanced -> Environment Variables -> System Variables -> Select Path variable -> append the below value.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32
```

It should work with that change.

Comment: sorry I didn't seen you post. I did same thing What you suggested.It's working great.

Answer (score 2):

@All, Finally I got it,why I am getting this problem `'findstr' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`
Because the following path `C:\Windows\System32` was not set in Environment variables. I found through google.I fix it and run my server it's working great.

Thank you guys for your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to your bin folder `P:\Software\JBOSS\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin\` and then execute `run.bat` or `standalone.bat`

If you still get errors, you should delete your entire JBoss folder and then install it again and try to run it with the default settings. Once you've confirmed that works, change the settings 1 by 1 so that you know which setting caused your server to not start up.

Comment: Re-install means, I need to close Environment variables and re-create again.Is it right?

Comment: You don't need to recreate your environment variables, they are in your operating system, not your jboss installation. you only need to delete your jboss folder, and then unpack it from the zip again so that all the files are back to their default.

Comment: Still I am getting same error. otherwise can I try with previous versions of JBOSS.

Answer (score 0):

You could better add it in to any IDE(eclipse) and then deploy your application. That should be easy to manage your applications

Comment: I actually tried that, but I found it more difficult to manage. I think it's more an opinion.

Comment: @John we are not using eclipse.because we are working on `Wolfram Mathematica `