# Unable to start JBOSS AS 7.1.1 from command prompt in window 7

Tags: jboss7.x

I trying to start jboss as 7.1.1 from the command prompt in window7 and set the JAVA_HOME,JBOSS_HOME in environment variable. But the it showing below error message when using run.bat/standalone.bat

[image]

I checked this [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17441136/how-to-start-jboss-as-7-1-1-on-windows).Even this already setting path for system32 also.Its not working.Please help on this.

Update**strong text**

@Ramaraj

As per you shared comments I already done.but got this same thing.I share my system configuration also windows 64 bit and JDK 1.7 and  check below images

[image]
[image]

Comment: The error is "Calling "Calling "C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin\standalone.conf.bat".I shared screenshot

Comment: Try running `bin\standalone.bat` from the `C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final` directory instead.

Comment: Did you change anything in standalone.bat or standalone.conf.bat?
Can you post both files here.

Comment: I didn't changed any thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

standalone.bat is enough to start jboss in windows

could you set JBOSS-HOME in properties file like  JBOSS_HOME  D:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final then try to start

if you get 'findstr' is not recognized as an internal or external command error

then do

Click My Compuer -> Advanced -> Environment Variables -> System Variables -> Select Path variable -> append the below value.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32
```

then try to start jboss using standalone.bat[image]